# Specify maintenance page in .htaccess without redirecting to error page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have to make a maintenance page for my website with the .htaccess, I've searched on the internet and could only find snippets/scripts which redirect but I only want that it displays a message on the page itself for people, but not for a specified ip-address. So when I enable the script in the .htaccess it has to show a message on every page/ file(=css, etc.) except for my ip-address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=123.45.67.89
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/construction.php
RewriteRule ^ /construction.php [L]
```